# how to speed up Python nested loops for million elements

Tags: python, loops, numpy, vector, astropy

I try to pair two objects (one data set contains about 0.5 million elements, another one contains about 2 million elements) which meet certain conditions, then save information of the two objects to a file. Many variables are not involved in the pairing calculation, but they are important for my following analysis, therefore I need to keep track of those variables and save them. If there is way to vectorize the whole analysis, it will be much faster. In the following I take the random number as an example:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
from PyAstronomy import pyasl


RA1 = np.random.uniform(0,360,500000)
DEC1 = np.random.uniform(-90,90,500000)
d = np.random.uniform(55,2000,500000)
z = np.random.uniform(0.05,0.2,500000)
e = np.random.uniform(0.05,1.0,500000)
s = np.random.uniform(0.05,5.0,500000)
RA2 = np.random.uniform(0,360,2000000)
DEC2 = np.random.uniform(-90,90,2000000)
n = np.random.randint(10,10000,2000000)
m = np.random.randint(10,10000,2000000)

f = open('results.txt','a')
for i in range(len(RA1)):
    if i % 50000 == 0:
        print i
    ra1 = RA1[i]
    dec1 = DEC1[i]
    c1 = SkyCoord(ra=ra1*u.degree, dec=dec1*u.degree)
    for j in range(len(RA2)):
        ra2 = RA2[j]
        dec2 = DEC2[j]
        c2 = SkyCoord(ra=ra2*u.degree, dec=dec2*u.degree)

        ang = c1.separation(c2)
        sep = d[i] * ang.radian
        pa = pyasl.positionAngle(ra1, dec1, ra2, dec2)

        if sep < 1.5:
            np.savetxt(f,np.c_[ra1,dec1,sep,z[i],e[i],s[i],n[j],m[j]], fmt = '%1.4f   %1.4f   %1.4f   %1.4f   %1.4f   %1.4f   %i   %i')
```

Comment: For one, don't use numpy this way, because indexing is relatively slow on numpy arrays due to Python-C conversions. Numpy is supposed to be used in a functional/vectorised fashion. You are supposed to minimise pure-Python runtime by delegating as much a possible to numpy's functions and methods. You shouldn't just use `numpy.array` as a drop-in replacement for `list`.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Thank you. I am trying to vectorize the whole calculation. But I do not have a good idea how to.

Comment: In your program you have I/O access. You can minimise this by creating a intermediate buffer in memory, an flush it regularly (like you did with `print`) statement.

Comment: You are using Python 2.7: replace `range` by `xrange`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The basic question you need to ask yourself is: Can you reduce the dataset?

If not I have some bad news: 500000 * 2000000 is `1e12`. That means you're trying to do one trillion operations.

The angular seperation involves some trigonometric functions (I think `cos`, `sin` and `sqrt` are involved here) so it will be roughly in the order of hundreds of nanoseconds up to microseconds per operation. Assuming each operation takes 1us you'll still need 12 days to complete this. And this assumes you don't have any Python loop or IO overhead and I think 1us is reasonable for these kind of operations.

But there are certainly ways to optimize it: `SkyCoord` allows to vectorize but only 1D:

```
# Create the SkyCoord for the longer array once
c2 = SkyCoord(ra=RA2*u.degree, dec=DEC2*u.degree)
# and calculate the seperation from each coordinate of the shorter list
for idx, (ra, dec) in enumerate(zip(RA1, DEC1)):
    c1 = SkyCoord(ra=ra*u.degree, dec=dec*u.degree)
    # x will be the angular seperation with a length of your RA2 and DEC2 arrays
    x = c1.separation(c2)
```

This will already yield a speedup of several orders of magnitude:

```
# note that I made these MUCH shorter
RA1 = np.random.uniform(0,360,5)
DEC1 = np.random.uniform(-90,90,5)
RA2 = np.random.uniform(0,360,10)
DEC2 = np.random.uniform(-90,90,10)

def test(RA1, DEC1, RA2, DEC2):
    """Version with vectorized inner loop."""
    c2 = SkyCoord(ra=RA2*u.degree, dec=DEC2*u.degree)
    for idx, (ra, dec) in enumerate(zip(RA1, DEC1)):
        c1 = SkyCoord(ra=ra*u.degree, dec=dec*u.degree)
        x = c1.separation(c2)

def test2(RA1, DEC1, RA2, DEC2):
    """Double loop."""
    for ra, dec in zip(RA1, DEC1):
        c1 = SkyCoord(ra=ra*u.degree, dec=dec*u.degree)
        for ra, dec in zip(RA2, DEC2):
            c2 = SkyCoord(ra=ra*u.degree, dec=dec*u.degree)
            x = c1.separation(c2)

%timeit test(RA1, DEC1, RA2, DEC2)  # 1 loop, best of 3: 225 ms per loop
%timeit test2(RA1, DEC1, RA2, DEC2) # 1 loop, best of 3: 2.71 s per loop
```

This is already 10 times as fast and it scales MUCH better:

```
RA1 = np.random.uniform(0,360,5)
DEC1 = np.random.uniform(-90,90,5)
RA2 = np.random.uniform(0,360,2000000)
DEC2 = np.random.uniform(-90,90,2000000)

%timeit test(RA1, DEC1, RA2, DEC2)  # 1 loop, best of 3: 2.8 s per loop

# test2 scales so bad I only use 50 elements here
RA2 = np.random.uniform(0,360,50)
DEC2 = np.random.uniform(-90,90,50)
%timeit test2(RA1, DEC1, RA2, DEC2)  # 1 loop, best of 3: 11.4 s per loop
```

Note that by vectorizing the inner loop I was able to calculate 40000 times more elements in 1/4 of the time. So by vectorizing the inner loop you should be roughly 200k times faster.

Here we calculated 5 times 2 million seperations in 3 seconds, so it will be roughly 300 ns per operation. At this speed you'd need 3 days to complete this task.

Even if you could also vectorize the remaining loop away I don't think that would yield any great speedups because at that level the loop overhead is much less than the computation time in each loop. Using `line-profiler` supports this statement:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    11                                           def test(RA1, DEC1, RA2, DEC2):
    12         1       216723 216723.0      2.6      c2 = SkyCoord(ra=RA2*u.degree, dec=DEC2*u.degree)
    13         6          222     37.0      0.0      for idx, (ra, dec) in enumerate(zip(RA1, DEC1)):
    14         5       206796  41359.2      2.5          c1 = SkyCoord(ra=ra*u.degree, dec=dec*u.degree)
    15         5      7847321 1569464.2     94.9          x = c1.separation(c2)
```

If it's not obvious from the `Hits` that's from the 5 x 2,000,000 run and for comparison here is the one from a 5x20 run on `test2`:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    17                                           def test2(RA1, DEC1, RA2, DEC2):
    18         6           80     13.3      0.0      for ra, dec in zip(RA1, DEC1):
    19         5       195030  39006.0      0.6          c1 = SkyCoord(ra=ra*u.degree, dec=dec*u.degree)
    20       105         1737     16.5      0.0          for ra, dec in zip(RA2, DEC2):
    21       100      3871427  38714.3     11.8              c2 = SkyCoord(ra=ra*u.degree, dec=dec*u.degree)
    22       100     28870724 288707.2     87.6              x = c1.separation(c2)
```

The reason why `test2` scales worse is that the `c2 = SkyCoord` part takes 12% of the total time instead of just 2.5% and that each single call to `seperation` has some significant overhead. So it's not really the Python loop overhead that makes it slow but the `SkyCoord` constructor and the static parts of `seperation`.

You obviously need to vectorize the `pa` calculation and the saving to file (I haven't worked with `PyAstronomy` and `numpy.savetext` so I can't advise there).

But there is still the problem that it's simply not feasible to do one trillion trigonometric operations on a normal computer.

Some additional ideas how to reduce the time:

- Use multiprocessing so each core of your computer works in parallel, in theory this could speed this up by the amount of your cores. In practice this won't be be reachable and I would recommend doing this only if you have more than >= 8 cores or a cluster avaiable. Otherwise the time spent on getting multiprocessing to work correctly might exceed the single-core running time. Especially because multiprocessing might not work correctly and then you have to rerun the calculation.
- Preprocess the elements: Remove items where the RA or DEC difference alone makes it impossible to find matches. However if this cannot remove a significant fraction of the elements the additional subtractions and comparisons might actually slow this down.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a great idea to move on. I think one way to speed up is to have a cut on `delta_ra = ra1 - ra2 < 2 degree` before calculating separation. One thing I am not sure is when we vetorize the c2, how to keep track of the index, since I need the information corresponding to `n` and `m`.

Comment: @HuanianZhang If it's helpful feel free to upvote. Regarding your question: You can use (and optionally slice if you preprocess) an `np.arange(RA2.size)` array. This will hold the indices representing the values in the final (`x`) array.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation using a buffer in memory to reduce I/O. Note: I prefer using `io` module for file input/output in order to be more compatible with Python 3. I think it is a best practice. You won’t have lower performance with it.

```
import io

with io.open('results.txt', 'a') as f:
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    for i in xrange(len(RA1)):
        if i % 50000 == 0:
            print(i)
            f.write(buf.getvalue())
            buf.truncate(0)
        ra1 = RA1[i]
        dec1 = DEC1[i]
        c1 = SkyCoord(ra=ra1 * u.degree, dec=dec1 * u.degree)
        for j in xrange(len(RA2)):
            ra2 = RA2[j]
            dec2 = DEC2[j]
            c2 = SkyCoord(ra=ra2 * u.degree, dec=dec2 * u.degree)

            ang = c1.separation(c2)
            sep = d[i] * ang.radian
            pa = pyasl.positionAngle(ra1, dec1, ra2, dec2)

            if sep < 1.5:
                np.savetxt(buf, np.c_[ra1, dec1, sep, z[i], e[i], s[i], n[j], m[j]],
                           fmt='%1.4f   %1.4f   %1.4f   %1.4f   %1.4f   %1.4f   %i   %i')
    f.write(buf.getvalue())
```

Note: In Python 2, I use `xrange` instead of `range` to reduce memory usage.

The `buf.truncate(0)` could be replaced by a new instance like this: `buf = io.BytesIO()`. It could be more efficient…

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but the speed does not increase significantly. It is too slow. It might take a year to run this huge amount of data if using this brute nested loops.

Answer (score 2):

First way to speedup: c2 = SkyCoord calculated for every pair in ra2, dec2 len(RA1) times. You can speedup by making a buffer array of SkyCoord:

```
f = open('results.txt','a')
C1 = [SkyCoord(ra=ra1*u.degree, dec=DEC1[i]*u.degree) 
      for i, ra1 in enumerate(RA1)] )
C2 = [SkyCoord(ra=ra2*u.degree, dec=DEC2[i]*u.degree) 
      for i, ra2 in enumerate(RA2)] )  # buffer coords

for i, c1 in enumerate(C1):  # we only need enumerate() to get i
    for j, c2 in enumerate(C2):
        ang = c1.separation(c2)  # note we don't have to calculate c2
        if d[i] < 1.5 / ang.radian:
            # now we don't have to multiply every iteration. 
            # The right part is a constant

            # the next line is only executed if objects are close enough
            pa = pyasl.positionAngle(RA1[i], DEC1[i], RA2[j], DEC2[j])
            np.savetxt('...whatever')
```

You can speedup even more by reading [SkyCoord.separation](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/blob/master/astropy/coordinates/sky_coordinate.py) code and vectorizing it to replace SkyCoord, but I'm too lazy to do it myself. I assume if we had two 2xN coord matrices x1, x2 it will look similar to (Matlab/Octave):

```
cos = pdist2(x1, x2) / (sqrt(dot(x1, x1)) * sqrt(dot(x2, x2)))
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like two loops do not speed it up significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to reduce your dataset to <2 degree differences (as per your comment), you can make a mask by broadcasting (may need to do in chunks, but method is same)

```
aMask=(abs(RA1[:,None]-RA2[None,:])<2)&(abs(DEC1[:,None]-DEC2[None,:])<2)
```

In some smaller scale testing, this reduces the dataset by about 1/5000.  Then make a location array of the mask.

```
locs=np.where(aMask)

(array([   0,    2,    4, ..., 4998, 4999, 4999], dtype=int32),
 array([3575, 1523, 1698, ..., 4869, 1801, 2792], dtype=int32))
```

(from my 5k x 5k test).  Dump all your other variables through, for example, `d[locs[0]]` to create 1d arrays that you can push through SkyCoord as per @MSeifert's answer.

When you get your outputs and compare to 1.5, you'll get a boolean `bmask` that you can then `outlocs=locs[0][bmask]` and output `RA1[outlocs]` etc.

I've done similar things trying to do spatial derivatives on shells for FEM analysis, where taking the full rank of comparison between all the datapoints is similarly inefficient.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you expand your code a little more for me to get a better sense of it?

Comment: And also `aMask=(abs(RA1[:,None]-RA2[None,:])<2)&(abs(DEC1[:,None]-DEC2[None,:])<2)` returns `MemoryError` when I try 0.5 million * 2 million arrays.

Comment: Sorry, you should probably try to set up a loop that will do this in chunks of RA1 and DEC1, like `aMask=(abs(RA1[0:100,None]-RA2[None,:])<2)&(abs(DEC1[0:100,None]-DEC2[None,:])<2)`.  How big that chunk can be is limited by your RAM.  You also might want to pickle away the rest of the *1 arrays to save RAM space so you can do more of the masking and `SkyCoord` at once

Comment: As MSiefert pointed out, 500kx2M is 1e12, so a full-rank boolean matrix is going to be 125GB before you even start calculating.  A 1000-element slice will be 250MB, which should be feasible, and if you reassign it like `aMask=np.where(aMask)` it will make it even smaller so you can push a bigger array to `SkyCoords`.

Comment: Also, checking the documentation, `PyAstronomy.pyasl.getAngDist` might be more efficient.

Comment: Aand, [`search_around_sky`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/matchsep.html) seems to be what you are trying to do all in one step.

Answer (score -1):

`savetxt` used this way is essentially

```
astr = fmt % (ra1,dec1,sep,z[i],e[i],s[i],n[j],m[j])
astr += '\n'  # or include in fmt
f.write(astr)
```

that is, just writing a formatted line to the file